# Android Studio: Making a random number generator app, random number doesn't display?

Tags: java, android

I have EditViews to prompt the user for a min and max. The data entered is passed into an Activity function and a random number is generated. That random number is passed onto another Activity to be displayed. When I enter a min number and a max number and then click the button that says generate, I get directed to a blank screen. However, I'm expecting randValue to be displayed.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String RAND_NUM = "com.example.random.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void generateNum(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNumActivity.class);

    EditText minInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.min_num);
    EditText maxInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.max_num);

    int minNum = Integer.parseInt(minInput.getText().toString());
    int maxNum = Integer.parseInt(maxInput.getText().toString());
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNum = rand.nextInt(maxNum - minNum) + minNum;
    intent.putExtra(RAND_NUM, randNum);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
}
```

**DisplayNumActivity.java**

```
public class DisplayNumActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_num);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String randValue = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.RAND_NUM);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setText(randValue);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_num);
    layout.addView(textView);

  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.random.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Min number"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/min_num"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="min"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Max number"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/min_num"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/max_num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="max"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:minWidth="500dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:onClick="generateNum"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/max_num"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, two things:

1) In DisplayNumActivity, change

`String randValue = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.RAND_NUM);`

to this:

`int randValue = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.RAND_NUM, 0);`

Here we are reading in an int value from the intent instead of a String. In your main activity you saved an int here, not a String, the String here is just the "key" in the key-value pair. The zero is just a default in case it can't find your int.

2) To display the number you have to first change that int back to a String in order to set it in a TextView and then we display it to your relative layout like this:

```
String stringRandValue = Integer.toString(randValue);
View relativeLayout =  findViewById(R.id.activity_display_num);;
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(30);
textView.setText(stringRandValue);
((RelativeLayout)relativeLayout).addView(textView);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify exactly which layout you want to add your textview to.

Like: **RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayoutID);**

Casting to viewgroup seems bit heavy to me. Please try suggested way and let me know if it changes anything for you.

**Edit**: There is one more thing which I feel might be the culprit in this case and that is missing layout params for your text View.

Example:
***//create params like this***

```
LayoutParams layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
```

***//set layout params like this***

```
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
```

Note - replace the parent layout type according to your xml where this textView is been added.

Comment: Can you share xml for R.layout.activity_display_num ?

Comment: Have a look at edited answer and let me know if that worked. Still if it doesn't work then it will be better if you could share xml code for this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

> String randValue = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.RAND_NUM);

With this

> String randValue = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.RAND_NUM,
>   default_int_value);